Private PKG: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
Facing Error for this while connecting to mongodb (locally hosted) via mongoose.
I have created a custom pkg names as bifrost and updated the connection as
import {connect, disconnect, ConnectOptions} from 'mongoose';

export class MongoConnection {
  private config: string;
  private connectOptions: ConnectOptions;

  constructor(config: string, connectOptions: ConnectOptions) {
    this.config = config;
    this.connectOptions = connectOptions;
  }

  public async connect() {
    console.log('Connecting to Mongo Server ...', this.config);
    try {
      return connect(this.config, this.connectOptions);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Database connection error:', err);
      throw err; // Rethrow the error after logging it
    }
  }

  public async close() {
    try {
      await disconnect();
      console.log('Database connection closed');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error closing MongoDB connection:', err);
    }
  }
}


And imported this pkg in the sample service
import {ConnectOptions, model, Schema} from 'mongoose';
import { MongoConnection } from 'bifrost';

async function connect() {
    const option: ConnectOptions = {
        maxPoolSize: 5,
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000
    }
    const mong = new MongoConnection('url', option);
    const n = await mong.connect();

    console.log(`check connection`, n.connection.readyState)
    const user = new Schema({
        name: String,
        age: Number
    })

    const User = model('User', user);
    console.log(`check connection`, n.connection.readyState)
    return User.findOne({}).exec();
}

connect().then(console.log).catch(console.error);


NOTE: I have used correct url here so ignore it.
Weird:
When I direct use mongoose in the service its working but using private pkg is not working tried all solution nothing work.
mongoose: 8.2.4
node: 20.10.0

You are passing url as a string inside MongoConnection().

I have added the note
NOTE: I have used correct url here so ignore it.
So I am passing correct url only
But adding the actual url mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/testing?authSource=admin for ur understanding
